# how to traverse rails model to obtain a complex result(has_mas > has_many)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Maybe is simple problem that I don't see, but is a bit tricky to me right now

What I need is know which projects a user had bet.
I want to do something like:

```
some_user.bets.projects
```

my models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bets
end
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bets
end
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project
end
```

So, just to be clear, starting from a user instance, how can I know which projects a user had bet.

In sql will be something like

```
select projects.name from users
                inner join bets
                           on bets.user_id = users.id
                inner join projects
                           on bets.project_id = projects.id
           where users.id = 1;
```

how to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your `User` and `Project` classes as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bets
  has_many :projects, :through => :bets
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bets
  has_many :users, :through => :bets
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
user = User.first        # Find a user
projects = user.projects # and return the projects that have bets
```

Comment: You give me the way for sure, I need to change some other parts, but the way to go was the `:throught` thing, instead to hm to bets directly

Thank you